# Yii: Dynamically load new model with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, architecture, yii

I'd like to have a section with two dropdowns which effectively dictate which model to use.  I would like this to have a button with an onclick property that essentially clears the form, and replaces it with a new form, based on the new model.

Is there a way to do this in Yii, or perhaps a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Yes, this is basic javascript/ajax. When the select changes, send an ajax request to an action, and ask for a new form based on the value from the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with or without ajax.

With AJAX:

1. Render your view with a single form model and the form's options selected accordingly.
2. Create a new action that will respond with a json string encoding of the appropriate form based on the post param the action receives.
3. In the submit button click event handler, post to your new action which form you would like to receive.
4. In the post callback, swap out the form with the new one you just received in your response.

Without AJAX:

1. Render all the form models to the view.
2. Have the submit button event handler display and hide the forms accordingly.

Comment: Note: You don't necessarily have to write a new action, as you can have one action respond differently depending on whether the request method is a post or not.

Comment: This is the way I ended up doing it, except that my secondary action rendered a partial view instead.  If I remember, I'll post the code I used.